# Planar graph: Would an edge intersect if it were added to the graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I need to implement a simple, planar graph where every vertex has coordinates. A requirement of that graph is that I can quickly check the following:

If an edge e were to be added between two arbitrary vertices, what edges would e intersect with?

An invariant that may be assumed is that the graph does not contain any edges that are intersecting.

Algorithms I know about and have come across typically search for all edge intersections in a graph which would be an overkill in my case. I'm looking for algorithms with which I can build a graph step-by-step: every time an edge is added to the graph, I need to re-arrange the intersecting edges.

I know there are R-trees but I am looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want segment AB not intersect segment CD, that will be true if:

A and B lie to same side of the line CD
OR
C and D lie to same side of the line AB

1. **Light filter.** If CD is a new segment, make inequation to be correct if the first condition is right. If it is not right, no further checks is needed. Remember the inequation for the segment CD.
2. **Full filter** Check points C and D against all all saved inequations.